Thermal Smearing in Josephson Junction
I'm basically trying to simulate a josephson junction at a particular temperature. As per some of the plots I could find, the rise in temperature leads to a rounding of the I - V curve. I was wondering how to achieve this in a simulation.


This might be a helpful reference to point you in the right direction, although not entirely sure.  It discusses a Josephson junction simulation it appears:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1909.12421
A quote from the paper:
In this work we introduce a new open
source program named JOsephson INterface Utility Software
(JOINUS [1]) that incorporates SPICE-based simulator engines,
improved physical models and several powerful built-in routines.

The I-V curves in you show are based on the theory of Ambegoakar and Halperin (https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.22.1364). They derived a formula for the smeared I-V curve. The smearing becomes important when the thermal energy is comparable to the Josephson coupling energy, causing thermally actived phase slips to occur.
You basically have to numerically evaluate equation 3.4.21 from the lecture notes of R. Gross. See also the lecture notes for more background information. (https://www.wmi.badw.de/fileadmin/WMI/Lecturenotes/Applied_Superconductivity/AS_Chapter3.pdf).
